# Sorting by multiple attributes in R

Tags: r, sorting

I am looking to sort my output by two attributes. First sorted by grade and then by nLoans. So the output I am looking for would sort first all items grade A and then within grade A it would also sort by nLoans. Is it possible to sort in this way? I have tried the below, but it only sorts by grade and ignores the nLoans attribute.

````
> as.data.frame(lcdf %>% group_by(grade, purpose) %>% summarise(nLoans=n(), defaults=sum(loan_status=="Charged Off"), avgInterest= mean(int_rate), stdInterest=sd(int_rate), avgLoanAMt=mean(loan_amnt), avgPmnt=mean(total_pymnt)) %>% arrange(desc(grade, nLoans)))```
````

Comment: Put each in a `desc`, that should already be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking sample data,

```r
lcdf %>% 
  group_by(grade, purpose) %>%
  summarise(
    nLoans = n(),
    defaults = sum(loan_status=="Charged Off"),
    avgInterest = mean(int_rate),
    stdInterest = sd(int_rate),
    avgLoanAMt = mean(loan_amnt),
    avgPmnt = mean(total_pymnt)
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(grade), desc(nLoans))
```

BTW: wrapping it in `as.data.frame` is not doing a lot for you. Without it, it is returning a `tbl_df` which is a special-case of `data.frame`, so it'll generally work just fine as-is. If you *really* want it to drop the `tbl_df` variant, then you can simple add it to the end of the `%>%` pipe, ala

```r
... %>%
  arrange(desc(grade), desc(nLoans)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```